# books on audio processing open source projects and software

Tags: software-implementation, audio-processing, books

Because I would like to

1. understand how open source projects work and give my contribution
2. improve my programming skills and
3. understand better and implement algorithms in a real project

I'm looking for books.

The programming language is not the most important aspect: C/C++ would be perfect but any of the most common language is good.

A good example of open source project, and a very famous one in audio, is **Audacity**: the source code is easily available. However I could not find any book guiding or with implementation examples on existing source code for Audacity. Something on Audacity would be perfect.

Does anybody have a suggestion?

Comment: suggestion: Open Source projects usually have a hard time to find good developers and bind them. None of these will voluntarily sit down and write a book (it's very, very hard to make money with books for niche software). Also, learning programming from a book makes about as much sense as learning to ride a bike through reading. Basically all larger projects have contribution guides, so pick one and look for these, for the mailing lists and IRC channels.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I already know how to program and I do it for work too. For audio procesing, instead of doing throw-away projects on sites like Hackerrank or others or by myself I would like to work on something more concrete, on an already existing project. First of all for myself. If then, it is useful also for a community I will share my code very gladly.

Comment: So, pick a problem that you deem interesting, and find an (alive) project that deals with that :)

Comment: Yeah I was looking for a book because in such large codes is generally difficult to start and to understand how it is organized and some stuff is not obvious. I'll with this: https://mitpress.mit.edu/books/audio-programming-book

Comment: Yeah, but if you want to work with a project, you gotta work with a project. Again, picking a problem that you find interesting is a good start!